# Accidentally released a version that does not work on older Android versions

Tags: google-play

I managed to push an update to production that breaks compatibility with Android 6.0 and Android 5.0. It would be OK I guess if I selected the correct `minSdkVersion` (which I should have updated to 24). But the APK still claims the `minSdkVersion` is 21, but on such devices, it crashes on startup. If I understand that correctly, having 24 would not update the app on the older devices, so they would still run working older versions.

However, even if I update the `minSdkVersion` and push an update, those devices that already updated to the broken version will keep it and it won't help anything.

Any ideas about the best approach here?

I think I could somehow publish the old app version with a new version number, and then create a new release that would correctly update the `minSdkVersion` so that the older devices stay on that working version. Does that make any sense? Obviously I could try, but I don't want to screw up since this is in production track...

Thanks!
Jan

Comment: Can you push an update (not a reversion), with a new version number, that fixes the compatibility problem?  It seems like that would be the cleanest for all concerned.